# Did Agent Kay actually have IDs made out to INS Division 6?

Tags: men-in-black

> **KAY:** *We'll take it from here.*
>
> **AGENT JANUS:** *Who the hell are you?*
>
> ***Kay and Dee flash some form of ID.***
>
> **KAY:** *INS Division 6.*
>
> **AGENT JANUS:** *Division 6? I never heard of Division 6.* <sub>[Men in Black Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Men-in-Black.html)</sub>

Is there any canon (in or out of universe) information on whether the IDs they flashed to border agents were actually IDs for "***INS Division 6***"?

Or were they just generic looking government ID and "Division 6" was something Kay ad-libbed to them?

Comment: I always thought that was just some technological psychic paper type thing, tbh...

Comment: @Shisa - not sure about psychic, but I'm thinking something like changeable smartwatch faces, or e-ink paper (which is doable with modern Earth technology even now, never mind alien tech that can mind-wipe and make flying cars)

Comment: Richard is clearly being paid by the *italics* lobby :)

Answer (score 2):

**No, he didn't.** In the films you don't see the cards in any great detail but they are mentioned in the [official novelisation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553577565). The badge appears to be a generic INS agency badge and he then *adds* the detail about being part of "***division 6***" on his own, to confuse the deputies.

> *A tall good-looking kid of about thirty marched over to where Kay
>   stood, shined his black aluminum six-cell light at Kay's ID. Squinted
>   at it. "I'm agent Janus," the kid said. "This is my operation. Who the
>   hell are—?"*
>
> ***He finally made out the ID. "You're INS?"***
>
> *"Division Six," Kay said. He pocketed the badge case.*
>
> *"I never heard of Division Six!"*

Later on we see that they do indeed appear to have a range of vaguely official-looking ID badges that seem to suit for different occasions;

> *"I'm Dr. Leo Menville, Department of Public Health. This is my
>   associate, Dr. White."*
>
> *Laurel looked at the ID. **It had the man's name and picture on it, and
>   the notation Special Investigator under it. Looked official enough,**
>   and if they'd gotten back here past Larry and Tom, they must be legit.*

They're also (briefly) seen in the film's [official Graphic novelisation](http://www.comicvine.com/men-in-black-the-movie-1-men-in-black-the-movie/4000-196807/). Unfortunately the *full* badge is obscured but we can at least see that it says **INS** on it, which ties up nicely with the assertion in the novel that the badge is simply a generic one and that Kay adds the "division 6" bit himself:

[image]

---

Obviously we know (from the [original source comics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Men_in_Black_%28comics%29)) that the MIB aren't averse to using fake ID when they need to:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a common running gag in Men In Black. THERE IS NO DIVISION 6.

In the movie MIB, KAY references INS Division 6, which is totally fictitious (i.e. non existant).

During the `Men In Black animated series` (which can be considered canon also) there has been multiple references to this **"DIVISION 6"**. Where KAY or JAY reference to them being from departments such as --  **United Nations Security Division 6** or **Fire Marshall Division 6**

So, NO, KAY did not have IDs made out for INS Division 6, it was some random ID card show up.

Comment: What is the evidence that it's a gag and not actual ids?

Comment: I mean you really cant expect every time they identify themselves to civilians or other government agents they refer to "XYZ Dept. - Division 6".. It has been observed not once, not twice but thrice..

Comment: well, given that they are an agency with access to memory wiping technology, flying cars, atomizers, etc... - I am thinking it's extremely likely they have the tech to make a LCD/holodisplay ID that adjusts to whatever agency image is needed.

Comment: An out-of-universe explanation is that it's more humorous for them to flash a generic ID and sweet talk their way into places with it, so they may not actually have real IDs